# WPF SelectionChanged event for all items in window?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a Window with many items in it, is there a Window or Grid Event to tell if the user has changed any textbox, combobox, radiobutton, checkbutton etc? I don't want to go through each item and add SelectionChanged event as this is just to tell if anything has changed since the data was last saved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface which notify you once any property changed.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BindBetterINotifyProperty.aspx) is an example that describes "Bind Better With INotifyProperty". This example is for a Windows App, but hope it would give you an idea.

Doing your job in this way is much elegant than adding events for each controls.

Comment: that's not really what I was looking for, my situation is that if the user clicks quit when the information they have entered in the forms is not saved then they will be notified the information is not saved. I have the equivalent to bIsSaved=false, at beginning, upon saving bIsSaved=true, once any item is changed is there a way to have it switch back to bIsSaved=false, without writing it into the selection changed (or your posted way) of each invididual item.

Comment: I found out I can select multiple items for the same events, that kinda works, but I have to have different events for different items, so still not as smooth as I would like